# Serial communication 8N1: how to know start and stop bit format?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

Unfortunately, I am totally unfamiliar with serial communication, but I have a temperature controller which I want to control using python + pyserial.

I managed to connect to the device via a COM-Port. Then my next approach was to set the new temperature via the `serial.write` command. However, nothing happened.

My questions:

1. Do I need to send a startbit before and a stopbit following my „set new temperature“ command?
2. If a startbit/stopbit is needed, how does it typically look like?
3. How would the corresponding startbit/stopbit `serial.write(„…“)` command look like?

The code:

```py
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port = „COM3“
ser.timeout = 5
ser.stopbits = 1

ser.open()
#Serial<id=0x233e6e2e1a0, open=True>(port=„COM3“, baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity=„N“, stopbits=1, timeout=5, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)

ser.readline()
#b““
ser.write(bytes.fromhex(“01 06 00 00 00 69 49 E4“)) #<—- do i need to add start and stopbits here?

ser.readline()
#b““
```

Things I tried so far:

First I used a serial sniffer and monitored the COM-Port while utilizing the manufacturers software to change the temperature. The sniffer told me the command to change the temperature to 10.5°C was: 01 06 00 00 00 69 49 E4.

In addition the sniffer tells me, when sending a new temperature via the original software, that it returns and confirms the „hex code“: 01 06 00 00 00 69 49 E4.

When utilizing `serial.write(bytes.fromhex(01 06 00 00 00 69 49 E4))` in python with pyserial and subsequently using `serial.readline()` it returns an empty byte. Although I would expect to get my hex code back. Ultimately the temperature setting should be confirmed on the display of the device, but it is not.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
general available device information:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
The Device is a PID-PID temperature controller from the vendor Microptik and is called MTDC600. [MTDC600 Specification sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmwos.jpg).
To use the device with the provided software one has to install the uart bride driver CH341. [CH341 manual](https://www.wch-ic.com/downloads/file/16.html?time=2024-02-26%2002:15:00&code=wICFS6jWUSA14s82kCF1DwdsIdTJ9Xa0IF3rOsHO). Unfortunately i do not know how to get useful information out of that CH341 manual.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Additional information:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

One thing that seems odd to me is when i use the sniffer to monitor the com port while utilising the original manufacturers software it monitors all write/read commands seperately.
[Screenshot of the sniffer monitoring the com port while sending commands through the manufacturers software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSRjz.png)

However, when i send through commands via pyserial it rarely sends them seperately. It seems like sometimes they pile up as shown in the image below:

[Screenshot of the sniffer monitoring the com port while sending commands through pyserial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPJFO.png)

[Sniffer Protocol while setting temperature. Besides setting the temperature (red circle) the continuous background can be seen (marked in black circle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dcx8.png)

[Sniffer Protocol of the device response while setting the temperature. Shown is the response (black circle) of the continuous write from the screenshot 5 and from setting the temperature (red circle).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lio75.png)

Comment: Start and stop bits frame each individual character or byte as transmitted by the UART. The start and stop bits are stripped off by the receiving UART. Software need only configure the UART hardware at each end of the serial link for the same frame configuration. There is no framing of the message or packet at the hardware level.

Comment: "*When utilizing serial.write() ... and subsequently using serial.readline() it returns an empty byte*" - Your code writes a sequence of raw bytes, but tries to read a line, i.e. text terminated by an end-of-line character.  Such a combination of a binary write with a text read is typically illogical to use.

Comment: "*It seems like sometimes they pile up*" - The sniffer only displays what your code produces. You seem to have a serial device that expects its host to use a request-response message protocol. Your code (as the host) sends a command (as the request). The device will then respond with its message. But does your code wait for a sufficient amount of time for a response before it sends another request/command?

Comment: @Timbob , Please, instead of reverse engineering from sniffer monitoring data, obtain the communication specification document from the device vendor and program it. Also, when you ask a question on this site, you will need to be able to provide information about the vendor and model of the device in question. If you don't have that information and are only presented with monitoring data, it will only lead to inefficiency and wasted time for you and everyone reading this article trying to answer your question.

Comment: Unfortunetely there is no communication specification document provided. The vendor offers to sell a „communication package“ which is tailored for LabView. I add the vendor and device information to the question above. Unfortunately i have to do reverse engineering :/

Comment: All the requested information is added to the section „general available device information“ above.

Comment: The material presented is only a partial clipping, and the entire material is probably [this pamphlet](https://www.microptik.eu/sites/default/files/category-flyer/Temperature%20Controller%20%20MTDC600%20R.V.1.1.pdf). It is also incorporated into many products within the company. [Search Results for: MTDC600](https://microptik.com/?s=MTDC600) Since it is extremely multi-functional and the command/response/notification data is likely to have various formats and variations, it is unlikely that analysis from a small amount of monitoring data will reveal anything.

Comment: How would you tackle this task? I believe reverse engineering of some sort is the only way, but with my limited knowledge i am left wondering: how should i proceed? I would really appreciate it if you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way to send the block of bytes to set the new temperature.

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, write_timeout=1)
time.sleep(3)   # Wait for Arduino to reboot

bytes_sent = ser.write([0x01, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x69, 0x49, 0xE4])
print(f"Sent {bytes_sent} bytes")
print("Receiving:")
while True:
    bytes_in = ser.read()
    print(f"{bytes_in.hex()}", end=' ')

ser.close()
```

Basically you are sending a list of hex bytes. You shouldn't need to change any of the defaults on the port such as stop bits etc. I have included a 3 second pause before sending the data because I have been testing this with an Arduino, and opening the port has the unfortunate side-effect of rebooting the Arduino. So you probably will not need that line.

At the end we display any bytes received, as they arrive.

Comment: It still does not work as expected :/. ser.read(8) returns 0bytes. If i repeatedly send ser.write([0x01, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x69, 0x49, 0xE4]) and than ser.read(8) i get back: b'\x01\x90\x04M\xc3'. Does that make sense to you? Unfortunately the temperature on the display still did not change...

Comment: I have edited the code to display each byte as it arrives, without waiting for the expected 8-byte block, since your device was obviously not sending an 8-byte block. I have checked this code against an Arduino, and it does exactly as you specified. If you cannot get the code to work with your device, you need to go back to the documentation to look at the spec for the serial comms.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort Lee-xp, i really appreciate your help and already learned from you!!! Unfortunately it still does not work. I added all the information available to me above in the new section:  „general available device information“. Please consider to have a quick look on that information maybe the missing bit is obvious to you?

Comment: Can you give more information about the sniffer screenshot. For example, what did you do physically to provoke the serail transfer of bytes, and what was the reaction to it on the device itself.

Comment: in your screenshot you sent four sets of eight bytes: 01 03 00 32 00 01 25 C5
01 04 03 EB 00 01 41 BA
01 04 03 E8 00 01 B1 BA
01 04 03 EE 00 01 51 BB   What happened on the device when you sent them through the original product, and what response do you get if you send them from Python using the code in the answer?

Comment: Thanks lee-xp for staying with me! I added two screenshot to the bottom of the post. Shown is the protocol of "write" and "read". Besides setting the temperature 01 06 00 00 00 69 49 E4 and its response 01 06 00 00 00 69 49 E4 one can also see the continuous write commands which are repeatedly sent as long the software connection to the device is open (black circles).

Comment: When you use Python to send 01 06 00 00 00 69 49 E4, what response do you get back?

Comment: I get back b‘‘ when i send 01 06 00 00 00 69 49 E4.

Comment: So the code I posted is working fine, and letting you test the behaviour of your device, which is responding to the data sent to it. So that's great, but I'm afraid I cannot help any further in trying to undrstand what your device is looking for.

Comment: However when i send the same command twice 2x(01 06 00 00 00 69 49 E4) i get back b'\x01\x90\x04M\xc3'

Comment: Thanks Lee-xp! i already learned from you and very much appreciate your time you put into this. Ill let everyone now if i make some progress.